# What does s(n) = s(n) mean?

Tags: integer-partitions, wolfram-alpha, python

I'm trying to create python analogue of wolframalpha's PartitionsQ function which calculates number of distinct partitions of integer. I found documentation about this function http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html with some formulas and trying to convert them into code. 
[image]

Would be:

```
def distinct_partitions_number(n):
    return (sum([
        (s(k) - 2 * s(k / 2)) * distinct_partitions_number(n - k)
        for k in range(1, n + 1)
    ])) / n
```

but s is described by these formulas:

[image]

[image]

And how can s(n) depend on s(n). What doesn't it mean?

Comment: There's no "$s(n)=s(n)$" apart from in your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sigma_1(n)$ is the described on that page as *the sum of  the odd divisors of $n$*.

$s(n)$ does not refer to itself. It's a bit unfortunate, but the $s$ inside the definition of $\sigma_1$ refers to the divisor sum.